Relationship between transition density function and local time
Assume the local time is $L(t,y)$ and we know $P_x(L(t,y) \in d\tau)$ where $P_x$ denotes the probability measure for a stochastic process starts at $x$. Can we then derive the transition density function $p(t,x,y)$ (from x to y after time t)? Or what is the relationship between $P_x(L(t,y) \in d\tau)$ and transition densitity function? 
Intuitively, I feels like $\int^\infty_0 P_x(L(t,y) \in d\tau)d\tau$ has some direct connection with  $p(t,x,y)$. Any kind of adivce is appreciated!
